# EF Connection String to SQLLocalDB

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6

I installed SQlLocalDB and created default instance "MSSQLLocalDB", after that I used SQL Management Studio to attach a DB to the "MSSQLLocalDB" instance.

I have a C# app that uses EF 6.1.3 and in the connection string for the App.config file I have

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDBName"
         connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=MyDBName;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

But is not working... Any thoughts? I tried different combinations but is not working...

The Same Connection String works if I m using a SQL Express instance... and instead of using

```
Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB
```

I use

```
Data Source=.\SQLExpress
```

Comment: Are there any errors/exceptions thrown?

Comment: Also, shouldn't `name=` be the dbContextName?

Comment: @J_PT try it (localdb)\v11.0

Comment: In this case I substitute the context name by MyDBName, but in my connection string is using the correct one. No errors are shown, I m using a release version in a different machine with localdb installed. The application starts but no data is shown, the problem is related to the connection string to the localdb

Comment: I m using v 13.1.4001.0, I tried v13.1, v13.0 but it does not work. I know that this works because I have a different computer in a different site working with localdb, but unfortunately I have no access to that PC now...

Comment: Details are 
C:\>sqllocaldb i MSSQLLocalDB
Name:               MSSQLLocalDB
Version:            13.1.4001.0
Shared name:
Owner:              pcname\UserName
Auto-create:        Yes
State:              Running
Last start time:    1/27/2017 4:47:36 PM
Instance pipe name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#D5A8BF9C\tsql\query

Comment: Another weird thing is that I can delete the Database after I attached to LocalSQLDB instance "MSSQLLocalDB", should nt the MSSQLLocalDB lock the mdf and log files?

Comment: How to proper attach an existing DB to a a localdb instance?

Comment: You may need to add [AttachDbName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx#localdb) parameter.

Comment: Thank you all, I found the solution.... The config file didn`t have the correct name, I was using App.config and it was ExecFilename.exe.config, after I rename the file start working fine.